# Java - ArrayList removal of duplicate items

Tags: java, collections, scjp, ocpjp

In the following example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("hi");
        list.add("hi");
        list.add("hi");

        list.remove("hi");

        System.out.println(list); //prints [hi, hi]

}
```

The ArrayList is reduced by one but which one does it remove? Does it remove the last inserted or the earliest inserted one?

Comment: You could test this yourself using different list elements, you know. https://ideone.com/1nYVN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`List#add()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) is documented to add to the *end* of the list, and [`List#remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) is documented to return the *first* matching item it encounters, your call above will remove the earliest inserted instance of the string "hi."

Since the printed representation of the three objects in the list are all the same, it's hard to *see* the difference in behavior. However, if you look at the instance addresses in a debugger, noting which one entered the list first, you'll confirm that it's also the first—and only—one to be removed.

In your case, given that you're using string literals, they are *interned* by the compiler (per [§3.10.5 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/lexical.doc.html)), so you'll see three of the *same instance* present in your list. In order to produce distinct `String` instances, try changing your three insertion calls to the following:

```
/* not final */ String h = "h";
list.add(h + "i"); // not interned, instance 1
list.add(h + "i"); // not interned, instance 2
list.add(h + "i"); // not interned, instance 3
```

Compare what you see in the debugger using those statements with your original program. Do you see a difference?

Note that if the `String` instance `h` above *is* declared as *final*, then the three concatenations will in fact all be interned, yielding the *same* `String` instance being added to the list three times. Thanks to @xehpuk for correcting my initial mistake regarding the *final* qualifier.

Comment: Have you tested your code? They are indeed interned because of the `final` allowing the compiler to replace `h` with `"h"`, so there are three references to the *same* String instance.

Comment: Before I posted the answer, I did test the code, which motivated me to write the last two paragraphs. It sounds like you're seeing something different. I'll test it again today and report back on my findings.

Comment: Testing again today, I see that you are correct, @xehpuk. Perhaps I had added the *final* qualifier only in the code block that I pasted into my answer. I corrected my answer and acknowledged your contribution.

Answer (score 7):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) - `Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present.`

Comment: Note that this is a property of all `List`s not just `ArrayList`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 2):

It will remove the first occurence it encounters, so the first one you added.